# Add custom properties to telemetry request at controller level

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I am trying to add specific properties to telemetry request for every route.
After digging a bit, I've found that I can create my own custom TelemetryInitializer by implementing ITelemetryInitializer.
By doing this I've managed to add global properties to the request.
However, I still need to add specific properties at the controller level.
Do you have any idea how can I achieve this?

I've tried to inject TelemetryClient into the controller, but if I use it the properties are shared between requests.

This is how I've tried to log in the controller:

```
private TelemetryClient telemetryClient;

public ValueController(TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
{
    this.telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> RouteOne([FromQuery(Name = "param1")]string param1, [FromQuery(Name = "param2")]string param2)
{                     
      telemetryClient.Context.GlobalProperties["param1"] = param1;
      telemetryClient.Context.GlobalProperties["param2"] = param2;
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> RouteTwo([FromQuery(Name = "param3")]string param3, [FromQuery(Name = "param4")]string param4)
{                     
      telemetryClient.Context.GlobalProperties["param3"] = param3;
      telemetryClient.Context.GlobalProperties["param4"] = param4;
}
```

And this is the implementation of ITelemetryInitializer:

```
public class CustomPropertiesTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public CustomPropertiesTelemetryInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties["RequestId"] = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetProperty("requestId");
        telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties["Ip"] = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
        telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties["RoutePath"] = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.Path;           
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that you're using at the moment, and give an idea of how you are logging in the controller?

Comment: Thank you for help Brendan! I've updated my question with the code that I'm using at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If the properties you added are always like "paramxxx", then there is a workaround(but it's really not very elegant).

In the controller constructor, check the GlobalProperties if it contains key like "paramxxx":

```
public ValueController(TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
{
    this.telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
    var props = this.telemetryClient.Context.GlobalProperties;
            foreach (var p in props)
            {
                if (p.Key.Contains("param"))
                {
                    props.Remove(p.Key);
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to use the DI framework. You can use it to get request-scoped data or services into your `ITelemetryInitializer`.

*(These examples are based on the standard ASP.Net Dependency Injection framework. This pattern should work with any DI framework, but will need to be adjusted slightly.)*

First, create a class to represent your request-scoped telemetry. I've used a simple DTO, but this could also be a service that knows how to fetch/generate the data itself. Register it using `AddScoped`. "Scoped" means that a new instance will be created for each HTTP request, and then that instance will be re-used within that request.

Because I used a DTO, I didn't bother with an interface--you should use an interface if the class contains any logic you'll want to mock in unit tests.

```cs
public class RequestScopedTelemetry 
{
    public string MyCustomProperty { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
services.AddScoped<RequestScopedTelemetry>();
```

Now, create the `ITelemetryInitializer` and register it as a singleton. App Insights will discover and use it through the DI framework.

```cs
class RequestScopedTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public RequestScopedTelemetryInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        => this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;

    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        // Attempt to resolve the request-scoped telemetry from the DI container
        var requestScopedTelemetry = httpContextAccessor
            .HttpContext?
            .RequestServices?
            .GetService<RequestScopedTelemetry>();

        // RequestScopedTelemetry is only available within an active request scope
        // If no telemetry available, just move along...
        if (requestScopedTelemetry == null)
            return;

        // If telemetry was available, add it to the App Insights telemetry collection
        telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties[nameof(RequestScopedTelemetry.MyCustomProperty)]
            = requestScopedTelemetry.MyCustomProperty;
    }
}
```

```cs
services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, RequestScopedTelemetryInitializer>();
```

Finally, in your controller method, set your per-request values. This part isn't necessary if your telemetry class is able to fetch or generate the data itself.

```cs
public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
{
    readonly RequestScopedTelemetry telemetry;

    public ValuesController(RequestScopedTelemetry telemetry)
        => this.telemetry = telemetry;

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        telemetry.MyCustomProperty = "MyCustomValue";

        // Do what you want to

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This solution didn't work for me. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Need this: using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

Answer (score 0):

In order to add per request data into telemetry, you need to have a way to share data within the request. A reliable way is by using [`HttpContent.Items` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.items?view=aspnetcore-3.1), which is basically a Dictionary.

You can create a service to keep a Dictionary inside `HttpContent.Items` with all custom data you want in telemetry (key prefix is used to ensure we only read the things we want later in Initializer):

```
public class LogTelemetryRequest
{
    private const string KEY_PREFIX = "CustomTelemetryData_";
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public LogTelemetryRequest(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void AddProperty(string key, string value)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items[KEY_PREFIX + key] = value;
    }
}
```

Register this as scoped in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddScoped<LogTelemetryRequest>();
```

Use it in your controller:

```
private LogTelemetryRequest logTelemetryRequest;

public ValueController(LogTelemetryRequest logTelemetryRequest)
{
    this.logTelemetryRequest = logTelemetryRequest;
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> RouteOne([FromQuery(Name = "param1")]string param1, [FromQuery(Name = "param2")]string param2)
{                     
    // telemetryClient.Context.GlobalProperties["param1"] = param1;
    // telemetryClient.Context.GlobalProperties["param2"] = param2;
    logTelemetryRequest.AddProperty("param1", param1);
    logTelemetryRequest.AddProperty("param2", param2);
}
```

Then read it within initializer:

```
public class AddCustomTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    private const string KEY_PREFIX = "CustomTelemetryData_";
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public AddCustomTelemetryInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;
        if (requestTelemetry == null) return;

        foreach (var item in _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items)
        {
            if (item.Key is string key && key.StartsWith(KEY_PREFIX))
                requestTelemetry.Properties.Add(key, item.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

---

Ideally `LogTelemetryRequest` should be registered using an interface, and the key prefix should be a single shared constant, didn't do for the sake of simplicity.